# AIDL IPC on an Android virtual device

Tags: android

When building a client/server app using AIDL can I test this on a virtual device or will I need to test this on a real device?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer is yes. I built a server client app using AIDL, but found that I had to target Android 10 as Android 11 requires queries element.